# Php extension with html extension

Tags: php, html, web, sendmail

I have a project with no php involved yet,no serverside work , and all the files have htm extension.But now i want to create a submit mail using php.
I'm wondering if I need to have all the files of the project as php extension ? 
Or do i need only the files that work with php have that extension and leave the others to html ? I have never done this before, sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only file you need with the `PHP` file extension is the one you wish to use `PHP` in. However make sure if you link pages using `<a>` then you add the `PHP` extension and not the `HTML` extension.